# Aggregating a list of records into two buckets

Tags: apex, soql, json, list, map

I have a list that has 2 months worth of records i.e MTD and 
    Previous month. This list is built from JSON response.

```
SubmittedDate   IDL (yes/No)    SubmittedCount

2019-07-01      Y               10
2019-07-02      N               6
2019-07-05      Y               3
2019-07-06      N               23
2019-07-07      Y               5
2019-07-08      Y               12
2019-06-01      Y               22
2019-06-08      Y               5
2019-06-12      Y               11
2019-06-14      N               1
2019-06-21      N               3
```

**I want to separate this list into two buckets, CurrentMonth and PreviousMonth, 
so that I can get the total for each bucket. And further, total for 
CurrentMonth where IDL == 'Y', and total for PreviousMonth where IDl == 'Y'**

**The output I am expecting is this -**

July: TotaAppsSubmitted = 59 i.e (10+5+3+23+5+12) , IDL (Y) = 30  i.e(10+3+5+12)
 June: TotalAppsSubmitted = 42 i.e (22+5+11+1+3), IDL (Y) =  38  i.e (22+5+11)

**My question is:**
How can I separate the records into CurrentMonth and PreviousMonth.?

```
public with sharing class MyController {

        public list<JSONWrapper> wrapper {get;set;}
        public integer previousmonthAppTotal{get;set;} 
        public integer mtdAppTotal{get;set;} 

        public void getDeserialize() {


            string jsonresponse = '[{"appList":[{"reportingPeriod":"2019-07-01","idl":"Y","submissionCount":10},{"reportingPeriod":"2019-07-02","idl":"Y","submissionCount":6},{"reportingPeriod":"2019-07-05","idl":"N","submissionCount":5},{"reportingPeriod":"2019-06-12","idl":"Y","submissionCount":16},{"reportingPeriod":"2019-06-13","idl":"Y","submissionCount":6},{"reportingPeriod":"2019-06-17","idl":"N","submissionCount":3}],"eclist":[{"dealerID":"XL1HX","submitUserID":"BCUSER1","bookedDate":"2019-05-22 00:00:00.0","ecEligible":"Y","caBookedCount":1,"ecBookedCount":0},{"dealerID":"XL1HX","submitUserID":"BCUSER1","bookedDate":"2019-06-05 00:00:00.0","ecEligible":"Y","caBookedCount":1,"ecBookedCount":0}]}]';


            wrapper = (list<JSONWrapper>) JSON.deserialize(jsonresponse, list<JSONWrapper>.class);

            getMTDTotalAppCount(wrapper);
            getPreviousMonthTotalAppCount(wrapper);

        }


        public integer getMTDTotalAppCount(list<JSONWrapper> wrapper) {

            Date datetoday =  system.today().format());
            Integer monthtoday = datetoday.month();

                for(JSONWrapper jw: wrapper){
                    jw.mtdAppTotal=0;

                    for ((JSONWrapper.ApplicationList cp : jw.appList) { 

                          integer reportingperiodmonth = Date.valueOf(cp.reportingperiod).month();
                          if ((system.today().month()) == reportingperiodmonth){
                            jw.mtdappTotal += cp.submissionCount;

                        }else{

                            jw.previousmonthAppTotal += cp.submissionCount;
                        }
                    }
                }

            return mtdAppTotal;
            return previousmonthAppTotal;
        }


        public integer getPreviousMonthTotalAppCount(list<JSONWrapper> wrapper) {


                for(JSONWrapper jw: wrapper){
                    jw.previousmonthAppTotal=0;

                    for ((JSONWrapper.ApplicationList cp : jw.appList) { 
                         if((system.today().month()) != reportingperiodmonth) 
                         {
                            jw.previousmonthAppTotal += cp.submissionCount;

                         }

                    }

                }

                return previousmonthAppTotal;

        }
}


public class JSONWrapper {

    public List<ApplicationList> appList{get;set;}
    public List<ElectronicContractList> eclist {get;set;}
    public integer previousmonthAppTotal{get;set;} 
    public integer mtdAppTotal{get;set;} 

    public class ApplicationList {
      public String dealerID{get;set;}
      public String dealerName{get;set;}
      public String reportingPeriod{get;set;}
      public String idl{get;set;}
      public Integer submissionCount{get;set;}
   }

    public class ElectronicContractList{
        public String  dealerID{get;set;}
        public String submitUserID{get;set;}
        public String bookedDate{get;set;}
        public String ecEligible{get;set;}
        public Integer caBookedCount{get;set;}
        public Integer ecBookedCount{get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the records? sObjects? Maps? Custom classes? What logic have you tried to accumulate these totals?

Comment: Gonna echo David here a bit. It's important to show us what you've tried so far. Remember, the goal here is to help you get unstuck in a way that helps you learn how to handle similar situations in the future.

Comment: @DavidReed and DerekF, I made  changes to the method getMTDTotalAppCount and tested it. I got the totalAppCount for Current month. Repeated the same logic for the method getPreviousMonthTotalAppCount, but haven't tested it. Not sure if my approach is correct though.

Comment: tested the code, gives me the desired result i.e totalappcount for current month, and previous month. Now will add logic to count records where IDL == 'Y'

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. You seem to have hit at least the first half of your objective, and are on the right track to complete it successfully.

Comment: @DavidReed, when i posted the question, I truly didn't know how i would achieve a solution. After posting the pseudo code, and then translating it into Apex,  as if by magic, the first half of my objective was achieved.  What I asked after editing my code is this - 'Is my approaoch correct? '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I'm seeing that you've taken can be broken down like this:

- Deserialize the JSON
- Call a method

  - Iterate over all apps
  - Accumulate and return some data
- Call a different method

  - Iterate over all apps
  - Accumulate and return different data

You could continue this pattern, and create a new method to iterate over the apps and just add an additional condition (only add this to the count if its IDL == 'Y'), but this makes your code a bit WET (write everything twice [or thrice]).

I think that a better approach would sound something like this:

- Deserialize the JSON
- Iterate over all apps

  - Call a method to determine if this *one* app record is for the current month, and add it to a total if so
  - Call another method to determine if this *one* app record is for the current month *and* has IDL == 'Y', and add it to a total if so
  - Continue calling methods until you run out of data you want to aggregate

A brief example of this approach:

```
// Since this data isn't really going to change while we're running the code,
//   it's a good candidate to be made a static variable
private static Integer thisMonth = Date.today().month();

public Integer currentMonthTotal {get; set}

public void getDeserialize() {
    string jsonresponse = '[{"appList":[{"reportingPeriod":"2019-07-01","idl":"Y","submissionCount":10}, {"reportingPeriod":"2019-07-02","idl":"Y","submissionCount":6}, {"reportingPeriod":"2019-07-05","idl":"N","submissionCount":5}, {"reportingPeriod":"2019-06-12","idl":"Y","submissionCount":16}, {"reportingPeriod":"2019-06-13","idl":"Y","submissionCount":6}, {"reportingPeriod":"2019-06-17","idl":"N","submissionCount":3}], "eclist":[{"dealerID":"XL1HX","submitUserID":"BCUSER1","bookedDate":"2019-05-22 00:00:00.0","ecEligible":"Y","caBookedCount":1,"ecBookedCount":0}, {"dealerID":"XL1HX","submitUserID":"BCUSER1","bookedDate":"2019-06-05 00:00:00.0","ecEligible":"Y","caBookedCount":1,"ecBookedCount":0}]}]';

    wrapper = (list<JSONWrapper>) JSON.deserialize(jsonresponse, list<JSONWrapper>.class);

    currentMonthTotal = 0;

    for(JSONWrapper.ApplicationList appRecord :wrapper[0].appList){
        currentMonthTotal += getTotalAppCountCurrentMonth(appRecord);
    }
}

private Integer getTotalAppCountCurrentMonth(JSONWrapper.ApplicationList appRec){
    Integer result = 0;

    if(Date.valueOf(appRec.reportingPeriod).month() == MyController.thisMonth)){
        result = appRec.submissionCount;
    }

    // There isn't really a need for an explicit "else" here.
    // We've set things up so that the default value is 0, and it becomes non-zero
    //   if we meet our target condition
    return result;
}
```

Now, this approach isn't perfect, and there will still be some repeated code (your check for `idl ==  'Y'` needs to also check the month). I would still argue that it's an improvement though.

- The amount of repeated code is kept small
- Adding new aggregations is simple and straightforward (make sure you have a variable, initialize it, add a new method to be called in the existing loop)
- Keeps the common code (i.e. getting at the `appList`) in a central location (as opposed to being repeated in every method).

Going from here, you'll need to add your own methods (and the supporting bits) for `getTotalAppCountCurrentMonthWithIDL`, `getTotalAppCountPreviousMonth`, and `getTotalAppCountPreviousMonthWithIDL`

Comment: Thank you @DerekF for the detailed approach suggestion and for educating me. I will close this post soon.